# Refreshing parent window after closing the popup

Tags: javascript, .net

I have a condition by which I need to refresh the parent window after closing the 
child window.

For example:

Suppose A.aspx is the page from which I am opening a popup (B.aspx).
When I close B.aspx page it should reload my A.aspx.

Note: I am using `window.open()`

Answer (score 2):

You can control main window in your popup by using `window.opener`

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function(eventObject) {
   window.opener.location.reload(); 
});
```